# Loading multiple instances of requireJS and Backbone

Tags: backbone.js, google-chrome-extension, namespaces, requirejs, instantiation

I am creating a google chrome extension which, when activated on a tab, loads some custom code and a few new views into the document of that window.  I'd like to use requireJS to load these  new modules of code called by the extension.  However, I worried about a possible conflict or name collision that might occur if the app/website this extension is called on is already running requireJS, and my calling it from scratch either wipes the sites native require.config or otherwise causes some unknown mischief.  This would cause the site to break every time my extension is activated on it.

So is there a way to load entirely new and "independent" instances of requireJS and backboneJS onto a site that MAY already have its own instances running?  If not, is there a way to reconcile my requirements and configs with those of the target app?

EDIT W/ MORE DETAILS: Ok, so a little more detail on my extension: I am creating an iFrame on the page, which has a completely unique document space.  But I still need the iFrame to be aware of certain things going on in the original document (ex: when the user clicks on a certain div in that document, I want this event to be passed to the iFrame).  To do this, I pass various objects through the original document's content script, up to the extension, back to the iframe's content script, and then finally (using window.onMessage), on to the iFrame's javascript environment.  The process I've developed is roughly similar to the one described [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/chrome-extensions-bridging-the-gap-between-layers/).  And yes, it makes my head hurt.

Anyway, the point of all that is that I have a LOT of code going on in the iframe, the extension, and the original source document.  So, I'd like to have a require instance in each of these contexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content scripts [run in a context that is isolated from the page's context](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#execution-environment). I.e. if the page declares a global variable `Backbone`, your content script cannot directly read or access it.

Drop the following code (just written) in your Chrome extension (put it after `require.js`), and you will be able to use RequireJS in your content scripts.

```
require.load = function(context, moduleName, url) {
    url = chrome.extension.getURL(url);
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // Append Math.random()... to bust the cache
    x.open('GET', url + '?' + Math.random().toString(36).slice(-4));
    x.onload = function() {
        var code = x.responseText;
        x += '\n//@ sourceURL=' + url; // Optional, for debugging.
        window.eval(code);
        context.completeLoad(moduleName);
    };
    x.onerror = function() {
        // Log error if you wish. This is usually not needed, because
        // Chrome's developer tools does already log "404 Not found"
        // errors for scripts to the console.
    };
    x.send();
};
```

During development, this method is quite ideal, because the line numbers will match the lines in your code.

In production, I suggest to use [r.js](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/) to concatenate (and minify) your code, because the output will be one big JavaScript file. Resources within a Chrome extension are typically loaded within a few milliseconds, but if you have quite a lot of modules, these milliseconds will add up to something significant. And each request is visible in the Network tab in the developer tools for the given tab, which is just noise, and an undesired side-effect for web developers who use your extension.

Comment: Hmm, but how do I load require.js in the content script?  From what I understand, require needs to be loaded from an HTML file, right?

The other thing I'm worried about is bloated content script.  Since content scripts run on every page load, it could really slow down the user's browser experience.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm trying to wrap my head around this and its just making me more confused.  So you are creating an instance or requireJS in the extensions background page, then shipping that instance over via a message passed to the content script?  Or...?

Comment: @AlexZ RequireJS usually loads scripts through a `<script>` tag. The code snippet in my answer changes this behavior, such that the code is loaded with XHR, then evaluated using `eval`. This maintains the execution context, thus your code is still strictly separated from the page's. To clarify: All of your code runs in the context of the [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html), not in the page or background page. How are you *currently* using RequireJS in your Chrome extension?

Comment: Ok, so a little more detail on my extension: I am creating an iFrame on the page, which has a completely unique document space and javascript environment due to the same-origin policy.

Comment: @AlexZ If you've got a completely different JavaScript execution environment, then why are you still worrying about potential conflicts with the page's code? It is not possible that the iframe's JavaScript code conflicts with the JavaScript code of the parent page.

Comment: that comment got truncated due the commenting character limit, so I updated the original post.

As for your solution: so what you are doing is loading the requireJS in the content script, because the content script shares the DOM with the page's native JS environment?  And since the content script doesn't have its own, sandboxed HTML document, we need to load require modules w. something besides the script tag, correct?  What can I do to prevent content script bloating though?  Loading a massive content script on every page the user loads seems like it will really slow Chrome down...

Comment: @AlexZ You're correct about almost everything, except for the last remark. You can restrict where the [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) runs by specifying specific [match patterns](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html). You can even load and execute code dynamically (e.g. using XMLHttpRequest + eval), if the presence of the application does not depend on a URL. Your last comment suggests that using an IFrame is somehow less expensive than using a content script, which is false.

Comment: The iFrame only activates when the user clicks on the extension icon, whereas content scripts run on every page loaded in chrome.  I can't use matching, because the user may **choose** to click on the icon on any particular page, so the content script needs to always be ready.  I agree that iFrame's are more expensive the c-scripts by a long shot, but iFrame's will only slow down the user's experience when they specifically launch my extension, while c-scripts will slow down the entire browsing experience.

Also, I'm really apprehensive about using eval().

Comment: @AlexZ You can use [`chrome.tabs.executeScript`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript) to dynamycally inject a content script. PS. Don't feel uneasy about using `eval`. It's the right tool for this job. You might have heard of "Eval is evil", but this only applies to cases when `eval` is abused for situations where the purpuse is **not** to parse and run a string as (JavaScript) code.

Comment: Oh, I totally didn't realize that!  Ok, that solves a lot of problems.  Thanks Rob!

Comment: Hey Rob, I'm still a little bit confused by how your code is intended to function.  What would be an example of calling this code?  I have put in a new content script called windowScript.js into my extension; it is executed whenever the user clicks on the icon.  I'd like to load some require modules within that content script; how would I grab those modules using this method you've written?  Specifically, what would I use as the context and url parameters?  Do you mind giving me an example?  Thanks Rob!

Comment: @AlexZ You don't "call" my method directly. Load it right after `require.js`, and use RequireJS as usual. Here's an example: `require(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone'],function($, _, Backbone) { $('body').on('click',function(e){alert(e);});});`. Without my code, RequireJS will try to resolve the modules relative to the current page, and load the modules *in* the page instead of the content script. With my method, modules are correctly resolved relative to your Chrome extension, and executed in the context of the content script.

Comment: Hey Rob, I'm having some trouble with the methods you outline here.  As far as I can tell, I have 3 contexts:

1.  My extension JS environment
2.  The JS environment of whatever page I'm loading the extension on
3.  The JS environment of my Content Script

As far as I can tell, these three environments are opaque to one another (ie, they all have distinct "Window" globals).  In your examples, you say to run your bit of code "after I load require.js."  In what context would I do that?  In the extension context?  But then how do I pass the require variable to the content script?

Comment: Never mind, figured out that I need to list it in the manifest content_scripts:[{'js'}] array before I load my actual script.  Thanks for the help!